# Position of MIME in the Networking stack

Tags: email, browser, smtp

Based on a what I found on the internet, **[MIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828352/what-is-a-mime-type?rq=1)** (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions, now [Internet Media Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) (?)) is a way to **describe file types** (**a header used by several protocols**).

So, MIME itself is not a protocol, rather an extension used by other protocols, right ?

**This means that the extension is used at the application layer by the applications with no protocol doing anything other than carrying the MIME header.**

So, if I send a mail with a mp3 attachment, SMTP/other application layer protocol recognizes that this is an mp3 attachment or it is **the duty of the application solely** to recognize the file? In that sense, MIME cannot be called as an extension to SMTP but rather a feature to be used by applications.

If **SMTP does not recognize** that this is a different kind of file, how will it properly **store it at the mail server** ? (e.g. a MPEG video file needs a particular format to be stored, how will mail server store it without giving it any special treatment ? )

Sorry if my questions sound a bit vague but I want to get an idea of how different protocols (especially, SMTP) use MIME.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'd be much enlightened if you sent yourself a short video by email and examined the source of the incoming message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC 822 email was originally purely plain-text, 7-bit US-ASCII. MIME specifies a facility for encapsulating other media types in email containers. It does not specify any changes to SMTP (although e.g. the 8BITMIME ESMTP extension is useful for simplifying transport of MIME messages). Thus, it is an extension of an existing protocol, not a distinct protocol in its own right. This is also demonstrated by the fact that other protocols -- notably, HTTP -- have incorporated (parts of) MIME for tagging of content types and encodings.

An Internet Media Type is only one aspect of what MIME used to codify; the mechanisms for specifying character sets and encodings are still defined in MIME proper.

Traditionally, the mail server simply stores the bare RFC822 message in its message store; it is the responsibility of the mail client to parse and possibly manipulate any MIME structure in the body for display and interaction. (The fact that RFC 822 has been superseded by 2282 and then 5322 has not fundamentally changed the actual mail message format.)

Some servers deviate from this model; for example, Microsoft Exchange seems to parse all incoming messages in order to borg them into its internal format, somewhat to the detriment of its interoperability with standard tools, and the sanity of those few of us who require reliable, felicitous access to our actual email.

Answer (score 1):

The SMTP protocol itself knows nothing about the MIME format, but the SMTP server itself has to at least implement basic rfc0822 support in order to ad the Received headers, however, it does not need to implement MIME.

How does the server save the file to disk? The same way it received it from the client over the TCP/IP stream. It just saves the raw bytes sent (with the addition of the addition of a Received header I mentioned).

In other words, you are way over-thinking this. The SMTP server doesn't have to know anything about mp3 file attachments or anything else because the MIME format (it's not a protocol) is just a way to serialize the mp3 data in a message.