# Why doesn't the subtype of this custom MIME type specify the particular row (from Content URI) in the table?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, mime-types

AT the end of [the developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html), they have described `vnd.android.cursor.dir` to be the `type` part of every custom MIME type, for multiple rows; and `vnd.android.cursor.item` for a single row.

Then there is an example of a Content Provider that contains train timetables. It's `authority` is `com.example.trains` and it has tables `Line1`, `Line2`, and `Line3`. And for it's content URI

```
content://com.example.trains/Line2/5
```

which is obviously pointing to the "*5th row in the `Line2` table*", the MIME type returned will be:

```
vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.line2
```

which does not indicate which row it is.

***QUESTIONS:***

1. I think it **should be** something like:

   ```
   vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.line2.5
   ```

   **because the `type` part does describe that it is the MIME type for a particular row, so the subtype should also describe which row it
   is. Isn't it?**
2. If `vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.line2` is correct, then that means it does not matter if the MIME type is of a particular row. **Does it mean all the rows in a table have the same MIME type?** Because a MIME type is simply the type of files on the internet. ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828352/what-is-a-mime-type#answer-3828381)) So I think since all the rows have the same "types" of data (or in other words the rows in a table are kinda instances of the same thing) - so I think all rows in a table should inherently have the same MIME type?
3. If ^ is YES, **then what is the point of having the categorization** into the `vnd.android.cursor.dir` and `vnd.android.cursor.item` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it should be something like:
>
> `vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.line2.5`
>
> because the type part does describe that it is the MIME type for a particular row, so the subtype should also describe which row it is. Isn't it?

No, no more than the MIME type for this Web page is `text/html.30821182` because it happens to be question #30821182 on this Web site. MIME types in Android represent data *formats*.

> Does it mean all the rows in a table have the same MIME type?

In that provider, yes.

> Because a MIME type is simply the type of files on the internet.

Android stretches the definition of a MIME type to be more generic than just files. In the case of the database-style API of a `ContentProvider`, the MIME type is mostly there to link the data structure for a `Uri` with an activity that can work with that data structure.

> I think all rows in a table should inherently have the same MIME type?

That is the typical pattern for the database-style `ContentProvider` API.

> then what is the point of having the categorization into the vnd.android.cursor.dir and vnd.android.cursor.item ?

The former represents a collection of content, what you would think of as a table or view in a SQL database. The latter represents an instance of content, what you would think of as a row in a table or view in a SQL database.