# Iron renders html as text

Tags: html, web, rust, iron

A part of my Iron web application:

```
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref TEMPLATES: Tera = {
        let mut tera = compile_templates!("templates/**/*");
        tera.autoescape_on(vec!["html", ".sql"]);
        tera
    };
}

fn index(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let ctx = Context::new();
    Ok(Response::with((iron::status::Ok, TEMPLATES.render("home/index.html", &ctx).unwrap())))
}
```

It renders an HTML template as text in a browser. Why not HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you didn't set your content's [MIME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828352/what-is-a-mime-type#3828381) type.
For full examples on how to fix this, see [Iron's own examples](https://github.com/iron/iron/blob/master/examples/content_type.rs).

One possibility would be:

```
use iron::headers::ContentType;

fn index(_: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let ctx = Context::new();
    let content_type = ContentType::html().0;
    let content = TEMPLATES.render("home/index.html", &ctx).unwrap();
    Ok(Response::with((content_type, iron::status::Ok, content)))
}
```

Comment: how can I set html content-type by default?

Comment: You unfortunately can't, as far as I know. What you can is wrap `Ok(Response::with((content_type, iron::status::Ok, content)))` into an own function that takes only `content` as a parameter.  If this has answered your question about why your template wasn't displaying as HTML, consider selecting my answer as accepted :)