# Uploading a data URI pdf file using Google Drive API, Angular and Node JS

Tags: node.js, angular, pdf, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload a pdf file to google drive using the API. In the Google drive api documentation the only way to pass the file is by indicating the path on on your local pc with the use of `fs.createReadStream`.
[image: google drive api documentation]

However in my front end, i'm getting the file as a pdf with the help of jspdf and autotable:

```
const doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'px', 'a4') as jsPDFWIthPlugin
doc.autoTable({
  head: [["Payment", "Payment Date", "Loan Amount", "Amortization Payment", "Balance"]],
  body: this.scheduleArray
})
this.pdf = doc.output("blob")
this.data = doc.output('datauristring')
doc.save("table.pdf")
```

In the google drive api documentation it says I can upload to a google drive by specifying the local path for example `fs.createReadStream('files/photo.jpg)`. But what if I want to upload a pdf that is for example in the form of a base64 encoded string like a data URI. How can files like that be uploaded using the google drive api?

Comment: I cannot understand about `Is there a way I can replace fs.createReadStream('files/photo.jpg') in the body of the google api with this.data I got from my front end?`. I apologize for this. Do you want to convert the JPEG data to PDF?

Comment: In the google drive api documentation it says I can upload to a google drive by specifying the local path for example fs.createReadStream('files/photo.jpg). But what if i want to upload a pdf that is for example in the form of a base64 encoded string like a data URI. How can files like that be uploaded using the google drive api?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I edited the question

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, was this answer useful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58253659 If you have the issue, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Yes this solution worked!. Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I edit the tags and flagged this as the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58251141

Comment: yes the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/58253659/10567291 from that post solved my issue