# How to upload images using Google Drive API v3 (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, file-upload, google-drive-api, drive

I want to upload PNG images into a specific folder in Drive. On the frontend, I'm converting a HTML canvas to its `dataURL`, and sending this to my server.

On my server, I have similar code as what's instructed in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#multipart). The only thing different is that I'm passing `dataURL` to the `body` attribute. The file gets created in Drive and has the correct file size. But the file doesn't show the image at all. When I download it it says the image is damaged.

How can I fix this?

Server code:

```
const uploadPNGToFolder = (folderId, fileName, dataURL) => {
  const fileMetadata = {
    name: fileName,
    parents: [folderId],
  };

  const media = {
    mimeType: 'image/png',
    body: dataURL,
  };

  const { auth } = this;

  return google.drive('v3').files.create(
    {
      resource: fileMetadata,
      media,
      fields: 'id',
      auth, 
      corpora: 'teamDrive',
      includeTeamDriveItems: 'true',
      supportsTeamDrives: 'true',
      teamDriveId: process.env.CLINIC_TEAM_DRIVE,
    },
    (err, file) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log('File: ', file.id);
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58251141

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you, your answer in that thread worked!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I proposed your question as the duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/q/58251141