# refusing to apply style in lightning because MIME type(html/css) is nt a supported styleshhet

Tags: css, media-queries, salesforce-lightning

I'm new to salesforce lightning & trying to make responsive design
by media queries &  calling the class columngap in div like this

```
@media  all and (max-width : 1280px) {
 .THIS.columngap {    
     color : red;
    }
}

<div class=" columngap">
     Contact Us
 </div>
```

so I keep getting error in inspect that mime-type is not supported &
**strict MIME checking is enabled**
So can anyone pls tell me how can I resolve it?

Comment: I would suggest that you provide some more of your code, this would help others to better understand your issue and better provide the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

MIME type defines the contents of your file, similarly as file extensions do. Just as you can assume, that `.txt` is a plain-text file and `.css` is a stylesheet, [MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828352/what-is-a-mime-type) is a way to tell (usually by a server to a browser), what the file is about.

In your case, `html/css` should be `text/css`, as the first one probably doesn't exists, at least not in [MIME types (IANA media types) list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)