# Why is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the default mime type for forms, if it is non-standard?

Tags: forms, mime-types

In [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828352/what-is-a-mime-type/34486815#34486815) we can read that

> The x- prefix of a MIME subtype simply means that it's non-standard.

while in [this W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) we can read:

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> This is the default content type.

Why is the default content type for form values a non-standard mime type?